# apache sling s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3, sling

Within Apache Sling 11 is there a way to enable one of the folders within the content repository to be synchronized with an S3 bucket. Essentially allowing the use of multiple buckets if so desired or this a practice that should not be taken?

Comment: I've added the following to my sling.txt file and I see the configuration when the server starts up but I do not see any buckets being created in my Amazon console. I am not entirely sure what is the cause of the issue. Any help would be great at this point. 

`org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.S3DataStore
    accessKey=""
    secretKey="
    s3EndPoint="https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    s3Bucket="test-bucket"
    s3Region="us-east-1"
    connectionTimeout=I"10000"
    socketTimeout=I"15"
    maxConnections=I"10"
    maxErrorRetry=I"3" `

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason as to why the application was not creating any buckets within Amazon S3 as the server was starting was because I did not have the following installed within the server.

1. Amazon OSGi SDK installed
2. OAK Blob Cloud bundle

Once these were installed and I added the necessary config files such as the S3Datastore, SegmentStore and the DocumentNodeStore added to the repoinit then the connection to S3 was established. It just seemed that some of the information was between two websites:

1. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/data-store-config.html#AmazonS3DataStore
2. https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/osgi_config.html