# Use S3 Bucket with Sling

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, osgi, sling, jackrabbit

I am planning to use S3 bucket for storage in Sling.
As per my knowledge, the NoSQL storage under the sling is Apache Jackrabbit Oak,  and Oak supports larger assets storage in S3.

I found these document on Jackrabbit [1],  but unable to get it (may be due to my limited knowledge of OSGi)

Kindly help me with the steps to be followed to use S3 bucket with sling and please let me know if I misunderstood anything.

[1] https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/osgi_config.html#config-sling

Comment: What is it you are struggeling with? What do you have so far and what is not working?

Comment: @MofX First of all, thanks for your comment,
i want to store blob data in s3 bucket in apache sling,
but i have not understood how can i do it.

Comment: Could you please try this. Looks like a possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141716/apache-sling-s3-bucket